# How to select an invisible radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have the following erb

```rb
<%= form_with model: @car, remote: true do |form| %>
  <%= form.radio_button :color, "red", style: "visibility: hidden" %>
<% end %>
```

I need to click it in an RSpec scenario, so I tried

```rb
choose("car[color]", option: "red", visible: :hidden)
```

But I get

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError:
       element not interactable
         (Session info: headless chrome=116.0.5845.140)
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it correct to have the radio button hidden and to test clicking it? If yes, you can set the element visibility before clicking it `execute_script('document.getElementsByName("car[color]")[0].style.visibility = "visible"')`.

Comment: How do the user click this radio button in real browser? Do you have some label for example?

Comment: Another approach is to execute javascript that sends a click instead of making it visible.

Comment: Executing JS to set field values, or force clicks makes writing the test pointless since it's doing things a user couldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

Visibility hidden elements do not receive mouse clicks so what action is the user performing on your app/site that sets this radio?  That's the action you should be having Capybara do.  Anything else (executing JS to change the visibility, forcing the click, etc) is just invalidating the test and making the writing of that test pointless.

Additionally, what you provided is not HTML, it's the erb template.  Providing the HTML produced by the template, in the future, will allow people to give better answers.